# Studying the total variation of an Integral Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

Yesterday I was dealing with this problem:
Let $f : \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuos and nonnegative and:

$$F(x)= \int_{1}^{x} \frac{f(s)}{s} ds \hspace{5mm}x \gt 0 $$
$$ F(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} \frac{f(s)}{s}ds \hspace{5mm} x \lt 0$$

-For which $f$ we have $F \in BV(\mathbb{R})$?

-For these $f$ give a formula for the total variation of $F$.

Taking the case $x>0$,
I was thinking that because of $f$ is continuos by the fundamental theorem of calculus  it should be $F'(t) = \frac{f(t)}{t} \hspace{3mm} \forall t \in [1,x]$.
So $F'$ is continuous (because is equal to a composition of continuos functions) and we can use the formula:

$$T_{F}(x) = \int_{1}^{x} |F'(t)| dt $$

At this point we must choose $f$ such that 
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty} \left|\frac{f(s)}{s}\right| ds \lt \infty$$

Maybe I'm totally wrong.

Comment: You got one quarter of the first question allright. For the second question we also need the value of $F(0)$.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by 'one quarter allright? And also didn't understand properly why do we need the value F(0)?